# Metric space is a $T_1$ space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I want to prove that a metric space is a $T_1$ space. We have that $X$ is a $T_1$ space if for every $x,y \in X$ with $x \neq y$ there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of x and $V$ of y with $y \notin U$, $x \notin V$.

Let $(,\rho)$ be a metric space and $x,y \in X$ with $x \neq y$. We have that $\exists \;\epsilon > 0$ s.t. $\rho(x,y)=\epsilon$. We define $\delta := \frac{\epsilon}{3}$ and now $U:=B(x,\delta)$ and $V:=B(y,\delta)$. We have clearly that $U$ and $V$ are open 
neighborhood of x, resp. of y and $y \notin U$, $x \notin V$. 
So X is a $T_1$ space.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. And you almost proved that $X$ is a Hausdorff space.

Comment: Well it's a bit strange to say $\exists \epsilon$ such that $\rho(x,y)=\epsilon$.  Just define $\delta$ to be $\rho(x,y)/3$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I could also prove that X is a $T_1$ space by the approach that a metric space is a Hausdorff space and so it is also a $T_1$ space, right?

Comment: @Dexter Yes, that would be correct too.

Answer (score 2):

If your only goal is $T_1$ this is simpler: In $(X,d)$, let $x \neq y$ and let $r=d(x,y)>0$.

Then $x \notin B(y,r) \ni y$ and $y \notin B(x,r) \ni x$. Done.

Your proof actually shows Hausdorffness, and even Urysohnness: $\overline{B(x,\frac{r}{3})}\cap \overline{B(y, \frac{r}{3})} = \emptyset$ but his requires a short proof, just as your disjointness claim needs a proof (in a student environment everything needs to be fully justified!) Just saying "clearly" is not allowed (yet).

Answer (score 1):

Let $<X,d>$ be a metric space and $x_0\neq y_0\in X$ and let $d(x_0,y_0)=r.$ Then the open sets  $U=B_{r/2}(x_0, x)$ and $V=B_{r/2}(y_0,y)$ are the neighbourhoods of $x_0,y_0$ respectively with $y_0$ not in $U$ and $x_0$ not in $V.$. Hence $X$ is $T_1.$

Comment: This is exactly the same as I did, not?

Comment: yes you are   correct.  I just modified the interpretation at a point 'there exists $\epsilon$'.